# mydomain.com/wp-login redirects to wordpress.com/wp-login

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, plugin-jetpack

When I visit mydomain.com/wp-login, it redirects me to

- wordpress.com/wp-login (in case I'm logged out of admin account)
- mydomain.com/wp-admin (in case I'm logged in)

This is perfect as long as I'm using my admin account.

However, I am using the Product Vendors plugin by WooCommerce. Approved vendors are not able to login as they cannot visit the wp-login page of my website. Instead, they are asked for a WordPress account on the mentioned page.

I tried different browsers, including a version one that I just downloaded (mo cookies).

In addition the mentioned extensions, my site uses Jetpack.

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to change you `.htaccess` file probably look like this:

**Note:** Don't forgot to clean your browser cache.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  /wp-admin/ /wp-admin/index\.php [L,P]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks CKG, I appreciate your support. However, I am completely new to WordPress so I really do not understand your answer.

Comment: This is the default WordPress `.htaccess` file.. When you faced issue of redirection then you need to clear cache after update `.htaccess` file.